# code works without the input at the beginning, why?

Tags: python, if-statement, input

If I remove the `spam = input()` at the start, the code works when I assign a value to `spam` manually. However, as it is shown below, when I am prompted to give a value to `spam`, whatever I give, it tells me "Greetings!" Why?

```
spam = input()
if spam == 1:
    print('Hello')
elif spam == 2:
    print('Howdy')
else:
    print('Greetings!')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` returns a string, but you're comparing it to integer literals (`1` and `2`). One option is to use string literals instead:

```
if spam == '1': # Here
    print('Hello')
elif spam == '2': # And here
    print('Howdy')
else:
    print('Greetings!')
```